# selenium issue while using InternetExplorerDriver

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer

i am using selenium 1.0.2 for my automation test cases, when i try to execute it from ie browser ,its launching , but its failing when hits driver. `findelements` or even waituntil saying

> The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:39208/session/61215720-0870-47fa-a50b-ac97fb8b7bbc/window_handles timed out,

but same test case is passing in chrome. also have found the in ie it passes if i use the url - `http://omnichannelint.blob.core.windows.net/convcontrol-daily/HTML/AgentWidgetWithMock.htm` , failes when i use `file:////C:/WebResources/HTML/AgentWidgetWithMock.htm` have tryed same in localhost:8080 then also it fails, please any one help me fix this issue

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Are you using selenium grid? Are your ie and driver versions  compatible?